# How to prove that $P\left[(A|B)\,\cap C\right] = P\left[A|\,(B\cap C)\right]$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm trying to proof that $P\left[(A|B)\,\cap C\right] = P\left[A|\,(B\cap C)\right]$ using the conditional probability definition:
$$
P(X|Y)=\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)} \implies P(X\cap Y)=P(X|Y) \cdot P(Y)
$$
Expanding the left side of the equation using $P(X\cap Y)=P(X|Y) \cdot P(Y)$, we have:
$$
P\left[(A|B)\,\cap C\right] =P[(A|B)\,|C]\cdot P(C)
$$
I don't know how to expand $P[(A|B)\,|C]$ and how to proceed to prove the equality. How can I prove it?

---

**Context:**

I was trying to solve a conditional probability problem in which one of the given values was $P[(A|B) \cap C]$. The problem asked for $P(A\cap B \cap C)$.

So, to solve it, I used:
$$
P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(C)\cdot P(B|C) \cdot P(A|B \cap C)
$$

And that's why I'm trying to prove that $P\left[(A|B)\,\cap C\right] = P\left[A|\,(B\cap C)\right]$: to use the data given by the problem in the formula above.

Comment: You need to define $P\left[(A|B)\,\cap C\right]$ - how you understand it?

Comment: What kind of unholy abuse of notation is this?

Comment: @zkutch I understand it as the probability of: A given that B occurred and the intersection of that with C. I don't know if I'm right.

Comment: Words "A given that B occurred " we used for conditional probability. If you speaking about event, then, may be, you mean $A \cap B$? Or something like "occur C in condition that occur A in condition that occur B"?

Comment: "A given B" is not an event.  When we write $P(A \mid B)$, that is really shorthand for $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$, provided $P(B) > 0$.  We cannot really intersect that with another event.  That is why zkutch asked you (and Renard asked, rather more rhetorically) how you understand this notation, which is decidedly nonstandard.  It may help if you replace A, B, and C with concrete events.  Suppose, for instance, that A = "it rains," B = "I wash my car," and C = "I get a parking ticket."  How do you interpret $P[(A \mid B) \cap C]$?

Comment: @BrianTung You're right, this notation is not usual. I put the parentheses to highlight something strange I saw in this [video](https://youtu.be/-UpcyoaJDJE?t=1127). Look what is written next to the Venn diagram.

Comment: I see $P(A \mid B \cap C)$.  I don't see $P[(A \mid B) \cap C]$.  Do you have a precise time in the video?  I don't really want to go hunting for it.

Comment: @BrianTung It's already in the video link from my last comment (18:47). As I said, I put the parentheses to highlight what was said in the video. Look what is written next to the Venn diagram (right side).

Comment: I saw the video, where it was advanced to.  I still don't see $P[(A \mid B) \cap C]$?  Where do you see this with the nested parentheses?  ETA: It may not help that I don't understand Portuguese.

Comment: @BrianTung He did not put the parentheses in the video. But, in short, he said the data the problem provided was $P(A|B\,\,\, \cap C)$ and we needed $P(A| \,\,\, B \cap C)$ and he "visually demonstrated" using the Venn diagram that these two things were the same.

Comment: Well, then the video doesn't help, unless he also says what is meant by $P[(A \mid B) \cap C]$.  As I say, that's nonstandard, so there's no conventional meaning for that notation.

Comment: @BrianTung So: 1) This notation is nonstandard, 2) The author didn't defined it and 3) The context of the video is not enough to infer more about it. Then, I think that maybe the author made a conceptual mistake.

Comment: @BrianTung I'm sorry for wasting your time on this nonsense notation. It's just that when I'm studying a subject and still don't have a certain degree of proficiency on it, I don't feel confident in concluding by myself when someone (who supposedly has more knowledge than me) is wrong. Thank you for your help!